# Trigger Plugin Execution after test on mvn test

Tags: java, maven

I'd like to use the SauceConnect plugin from https://github.com/saucelabs/sauce-java/tree/master/sauce-connect-plugin in my code.

The execution of the functions of this plugin are triggered by the different maven phases. I'd like to trigger the start-up (`start-sauceconnect`) right before the test phase and the shutdown (`stop-sauceconnect`) after the test phase.

My code contains nothing but tests, run via TestNG in combination with Maven.

Unfortunately I didn't manage to call the shutdown function (`stop-sauceconnect`), by calling one of the phases directly following the test phase. I'm normally running my tests via `mvn test`; but also by calling `mvn clean install` it never triggers the shutdown function.

This is my relevant maven code:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Include Sauce Connect plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.saucelabs.maven.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>sauce-connect-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <sauceUsername>YOUR_SAUCE_USERNAME</sauceUsername>
                <sauceAccessKey>YOUR_SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY</sauceAccessKey>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <!-- Start Sauce Connect prior to running the tests -->
                <execution>
                    <id>start-sauceconnct</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start-sauceconnect</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <!-- Stop the Sauce Connect process after the tests have finished -->
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-sauceconnect</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop-sauceconnect</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

As far as I understand it right, calling `mvn test` won't step into any phase after completing the test-phase.

So my question is: How can I trigger the execution of the shutdown function, after finishing the test execution (by either calling `mvn clean install` or `mvn test`)? Is there a phase that is always stepped into, or another plugin that helps me with triggering the execution at the right time?

Answer (score 0):

The best is can say is that this plugin is a kind of integration test and not a kind of unit test so it belongs more to the integration test phase ...where the following life cycle steps:

1. pre-integration-test
2. integration-test
3. post-integration-test

Binding it to those you can call it via `mvn clean verify`...

Comment: unfortunately this didn't help me to solve my issue, but it brought me forward in my understanding of maven anyways. Thanks :)

Comment: If you would do it that way it will sovle your problem. Running tests which are integration tests at the right life cycle helps.. Furthermore you should take a look at the [maven-failsafe-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/)  which will do more or less that same as maven-surefire-plugin does but for integration tests with different naming conventions etc.